# How to convert memory optimized table into disk based table in sql server

Tags: sql-server

Could anyone please explain the process to convert memory optimized table into disk based table in sql server?

Thanks & Regards,
Phanindhra S

Comment: memory optimized tables don't support `alter table`, so you're probably going to have to drop & recreate.

Comment: Correct. There's no conversion between disk based and memory optimized table. There's a *wizard" that can create a new memory optimized table that looks like a disk based table, copy data, rename etc. But not the other way around.

Comment: I would suggest to use `select * into new_table from current_table". drop memory optimized table (current_table). And rename new_table to current_table. SIMPLE

Answer (score 3):

> Could anyone please explain the process to convert memory optimized table into disk based table in sql server?

Create a new disk based table and insert the data from the in-memory table **or** use select into to copy the data over and create the table at the same time. There are various other ways but all are variations on this.

Please note that you cannot remove the in-memory filegroup from the database, so if you're attempting to clean up all traces of in-memory then I'd suggest migrating the data to a completely new database.